# Specifying only 1 type argument to generic?

Tags: generics, rust, nom

In an attempt to write a parser in rust using [nom](https://github.com/Geal/nom). I ran into this error

```
error[E0283]: type annotations needed
   --> src/parser.rs:8:22
    |
8   |     let mut parser = delimited(tag("<"), take_until(">"), tag(">"));
    |         ----------   ^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for type parameter `E` declared on the function `delimited`
    |         |
    |         consider giving `parser` a type
    |
    = note: cannot satisfy `_: ParseError<&str>`
note: required by a bound in `delimited`
   --> /home/user/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/nom-7.1.1/src/sequence/mod.rs:172:36
    |
172 | pub fn delimited<I, O1, O2, O3, E: ParseError<I>, F, G, H>(
    |                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `delimited`
help: consider specifying the type arguments in the function call
    |
8   |     let mut parser = delimited::<I, O1, O2, O3, E, F, G, H>(tag("<"), take_until(">"), tag(">"));
    |
```

Fair enough, I got this to compile and return what I need it to by changing the line of code to

```
let mut parser = delimited::<_,_,_,_, VerboseError<_>,_,_,_>(tag("<"), take_until(">"), tag(">"));
```

However, this seems like a pretty ugly piece of code. Is there a better way of writing this? A way to specify only the type parameter `E` rather then listing out all the other parameters with an underscore?

Comment: no [mre] no jutsu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function that wraps `delimited()` but with more specific generics. Other than that, there isn't much you can do.